# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'x' in treeview item

Tags: tkinter

**using python 3.7**

Hi. I am trying to get the the selected treeview item and want to print it once i click left menu item. This is my treeview list. When I right click a menu appeas with stop process command. I am trying to get the selected item and print it but its giving me error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'x' in treeview item
```

**Here is my tree list**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJRy1.png)

**Here is my code**

```
self.popup_menu.add_command(label="stop process",
                                    command=lambda:self.delete_selected("<Button-3>"))
        self.tree.bind('<Button-3>', self.popup)

    def delete_selected(self, event):
        item = self.tree.identify('name','ID',event.x, event.y)
        print(item)

    def popup(self, event):
        """action in event of button 3 on tree view"""

        try:
            self.popup_menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)
        finally:
            self.popup_menu.grab_release()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an `str` to `delete_selected` then trying to read `x` and `y` attributes of it. Don't pass the `"<Button-3>"` string to the method. Instead, receive the `event` parameter in the lambda and pass it to `delete_selected`.

```
self.popup_menu.add_command(label="stop process", command=lambda event:self.delete_selected(event))
```

Or simply remove the lambda and pass the function directly:

```
self.popup_menu.add_command(label="stop process", command=self.delete_selected)
```

Comment: When I do first of your solution it says TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event' and when I do second it says TypeError: delete_selected() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event' Thats why I tried passing '<Button-3>' but that also did not work

Comment: I don't know. Maybe place your lambda in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me

```
self.popup_menu.add_command(label="stop process",
                                    command=self.delete_selected)

        self.tree.bind('<Button-3>', self.popup)



def delete_selected(self):

    try:
        curItem = self.tree.item(self.tree.focus())
        item = self.tree.selection()[0]
        self.kill_process(curItem['values'])
        self.tree.delete(item)

    except:
         pass
```